# Ampersand in URL

Tags: cakephp, special-characters

i'm developing cakephp application.

i need some specific characters in url, like & (ampersand), because i need it for search purpose.

but, if i have ampersand in my url (like http://localhost/myapp/publications/index/string:Mono%20Manana/tags:publisher), it is rewrited and redirected as default url (in this case http://localhost/myapp/).

can you help me how to solve this and to use all kind of strings in my application.

thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the related code so we can see what you're trying to accomplish. Your explanation is very vague. If you're applying it in one of CakePHP's helper functions, there may be a special way to implement what you're attempting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use `urlencode()`?

Some of your source code would really help us to see what's going on.

Comment: We can't answer that precisely without any code, but you should wrap your values with `urlencode()`. Using your example URI above, `urlencode( 'Mono Manana' )` and `urlencode( 'publisher' )` would be appropriate.

Comment: You can't put & (and others) into the URL! You must encode it yourself when you add it to the URL. Otherwise the browser/server will do it for you resulting in an undefined behavior.

Comment: tnx. but i made function that will change Array ( [string] => Mono & Manana [tags] => publisher [url] => / ), to Array ( [string] => Mono+%26+Manana [tags] => publisher [url] => / ) , but i'm still redirected to http://localhost/myapp/ . what to do now?

Comment: Now you need to post some code so that we can get some idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

ok, just to mention that i did find solution, not with `urlencode`, but using `base64_encode`. hopefully it will do the job...